# Getting an empty Facebook news feed response using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: json, silverlight-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, feed

I am using the Facebook C# SDK in my Silverlight 4 browser app to perform some requests to the Facebook Graph API. I followed the example in the SDK documentation to request the user's information (using the asynchronous method to make it work on Silverlight):

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        fb.GetAsync("/me");

        fb.GetCompleted += (o, ea) =>
        {
            var result = (JsonObject)ea.GetResultData();
            var name = (string)result["name"];
        };
```

This way I get the JsonObject without any problem and I can read all data, but when I make request to "me/feed" or "me/home" instead of "/me":

```
        fb.GetAsync("/me/home");

        fb.GetCompleted += (o, ea) =>
        {
            var result = (JsonObject)ea.GetResultData();
            var data = (JsonArray) result["data"];

            foreach (JsonObject post in data)
            {
                id = (string)post["id"];

            }
        };
```

then the JsonObject is empty and I get a exception when trying to access its elements. I successfully managed to POST a message to "me/feed", but why do I receive an empty response when making a GET request? I have set the access token in the FacebookClient I'm using to make the calls, is there something else that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also set the "read_stream" permission

Comment: Have you verified that the user in question actually has recent wall posts? You will get an empty "data" object in that case. I am sure you have checked this but just making sure.

Comment: Yes, there are several published posts in the user's wall...

Comment: I have a similar problem when requesting to "me/photos" as well: as far as I understood the result of that request should return a set of links to the photos that have been uploaded by the user, and I have set the "user_photos" permission

Comment: It is now working without any changes made, maybe it was a Facebook server issue that has been solved

Comment: I'm currently getting an empty newsfeed using code which was working perfectly last week. I have to say that the Facebook API is one of the worst I've ever used, so I wouldn't be surprised if it was temporary problems on their side.